# solving differntial equation through transformation

Tags: differential

Transform the following differential equation into a second order differential equation such that the dependent variable is missing. Solve the corresponding differential equation.
$$
x^2 y^{''}-3xy'+4y=x^{1/2}
$$

Comment: Perhaps you could find a change of variables $s=f(y,z)$ so that $s'' \propto x^2 y''$ and $s' \propto xy'$? just an idea ...

Comment: ok will try to solve it like that

Answer (score 0):

HINT

I would say after substitution

$\ln x = t\\
y(x) = z(\ln x)=z(t)\\
\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dz}{dt}\cdot\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac1x\cdot\frac{dz}{dt},\quad \frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\cdots=\frac1{x^2}\left(\frac{d^2z}{dt^2}-\frac{dz}{dt}\right)$

we get an equation with constant coefficients:
$\displaystyle \quad z''-4z'+4z=e^{t/2}$